# gnuplot do not overlap lines

Tags: gnuplot

The folowing graph is generated with gnuplot: [image]

It shows 5 (but it can be more or less) waves. However, what I need is display each wave separately, like this (I did with gimp):

[image]

Is there a way to do this with gnuplot? I also need that each wave be a different colour, as I have now.

Here is gnuplot script used: http://pastebin.com/vAD2syTS

Here is the python script that gnuplot script uses to fix my data: http://pastebin.com/WEncNjDA

Here is the data: http://pastebin.com/ewBpvHWM

Here is the data after python script fixes it: http://pastebin.com/cgimMyr9

Comment: This is a tricky one if we can't assume that you know the number of plots ahead of time ...

Comment: @mgilson I can a script to find this out or something like that

Comment: I'm off for today, but see my answer ... It should give you something to play with in any event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had some fun with this one.  My strategy involves plotting the first, last and intermediate plots with slightly different settings in order to get the borders to line up.  I also define some functions to ensure that all the plot colors will indeed be different unless you have upwards of ~16 million data sets to plot.

```
### indices: change this parameter to equal the number of data sets to be plotted
indices = 8 
# h: height of output in pixels
h = 150.0*indices
# d: top and bottom margin in pixels
d = 75.0

### define functions to help set top/bottom margins
top(i,n,h,d) = 1.0 - (d+(h-2*d)*(i-1)/n)/h
bot(i,n,h,d) = 1.0 - (d+(h-2*d)*i/n)/h

### define some fun RGB code converter functions

# round: crude rounding function (gnuplot doesn't have this?)
# assumes a float, returns an int
round(x) = x-int(x)>=0.5?ceil(x):floor(x)

# i2h: converts a (decimal) integer between 0 and 15 to hex.
# returns a string, 0-F corresponding to 0-15
i2h(i) = i==10?'A':i==11?'B':i==12?'C':i==13?'D':i==14?'E':i==15?'F':sprintf('%d',i)

# i2r: converts an integer to an RGB code.
# returns a string (RGB code) of length 6, 000000-FFFFFF corresponding to 0-16777215
# changing the last division to 15 instead of 16 prevents colors being too faint
i2r5(i) = i2h(i/(15**5))
i2r4(i) = i2h(i%(16**5)/(15**4))
i2r3(i) = i2h(i%(16**5)%(16**4)/(15**3))
i2r2(i) = i2h(i%(16**5)%(16**4)%(16**3)/(15**2))
i2r1(i) = i2h(i%(16**5)%(16**4)%(16**3)%(16**2)/(15**1))
i2r0(i) = i2h(i%(16**5)%(16**4)%(16**3)%(16**2)%(16**1))
i2r(i) = i2r5(i).i2r4(i).i2r3(i).i2r2(i).i2r1(i).i2r0(i)

# rgb_iter: returns the i-th of n RGB codes, evenly spaced across the spectrum
rgb_iter(i, n) = '#'.i2r(round((i-1)*(16777215.0/(n-1))))

### first set up some basic plot parameters
set term png enhanced size 800,h font 'Courier-Bold,14'
set output 'waves.png'

set title 'Wave propagation by geophones'
set ylabel 'Wave'

set xrange [1400:]
set yrange [-0.15:0.15]
set ytics ('-0.1' -0.1, '0.0' 0.0, '0.1' 0.1)

set key out right

### now make plots
set multiplot layout indices,1

### first plot
set border 14
set tmargin at screen top(1,indices,h,d)
set bmargin at screen bot(1,indices,h,d)
unset xtics
plot 'temp.dat' index 0 w lines lw 3 lc rgb rgb_iter(1,indices) title 'Geophone 1'
unset title

### intermediate plots
set border 10
unset xlabel
do for [i=1:indices-2] {
 set tmargin at screen top(i+1,indices,h,d)
 set bmargin at screen bot(i+1,indices,h,d)
 plot 'temp.dat' index i w lines lw 3 lc rgb rgb_iter(i+1,indices) title sprintf('Geophone %d', i + 1)
}

### last plot
set border 11
set tmargin at screen top(indices,indices,h,d)
set bmargin at screen bot(indices,indices,h,d)
set xtics nomirror
set xlabel 'Iterations'
plot 'temp.dat' index (indices-1) w lines lw 3 lc rgb rgb_iter(indices,indices) title sprintf('Geophone %d', indices)

unset multiplot
```

The output on your sample data set looks like this:
[image]

The sizes of the top/bottom plots aren't quite perfect, and as mgilson said it would probably take some fiddling with `set xmargin at screen ...` commands to make all the plot sizes equal.

(If nothing else those int->RGB converter can be handy for specialized applications; I also have functions going from RGB codes to ints.)

EDIT: I updated the script so all the plots will have the same height.

Comment: why do the first and the last graph are smaller than the rest? I mean, their height is smaller

Comment: When using the `set multiplot layout X,1` command, each plot gets 1/X of the vertical area of the output file, and by default some of that space is used for margins/labels.  The top and bottom plots are shorter because they don't take up the entire plot area.  For the middle plots, bmargin and tmargin are set to 0, so they take up exactly 1/indices vertical area.  The top and bottom plots have nonzero margins to accommodate the title and xlabel.

Comment: I know that I haven't asked this but, where should I look at to have this graph rotated 90 degrees to the right?

Comment: There is no simple way to rotate a plot 90 degrees; it is not an option built-in to gnuplot.  If you google 'gnuplot rotate plot' you will find various kinds of hackery people have done, usually involving something like rotating all the labels in gnuplot, then rotating the output file with an external program after it is created.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. And what about plot the graph vertically? Is that possible? Maybe changing the input somehow

Comment: Actually you can plot vertically by inverting the x and y data.  You can do this with a command like `plot 'temp.dat' index 0 using 2:1'`.  That will use the first data column for y and the second for x.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the number of plots ahead of time (gnuplot 4.6):

```
NUM_PLOTS = 6
set multiplot layout NUM_PLOTS,1
do for [i=1:NUM_PLOTS]{
   plot 'temp.dat' index i w lines lw 3 title sprintf('Geophone %d', i + 1)
}
unset multiplot
```

If you really want to get fancy to make sure your borders and axes line up, you could use a combination of `set lmargin at screen ...`, `set rmargin at screen ...`, `set tmargin at screen ...`, and `set bmargin at screen ...` where the `...` are some function of `i` and `NUM_PLOTS`, although probably setting `lmargin` and `rmargin` at some constant position would be good enough (gnuplot should take care of aligning from top to bottom if you don't need to share axes).

`set border 10` will remove the top and bottom border lines if you really want that, but it's probably not necessary.

I'd recommend something like:

```
NUM_PLOTS = 6
set multiplot layout NUM_PLOTS,1
set lmargin at screen 0.1
set rmargin at screen 0.9
do for [i=1:NUM_PLOTS]{
   plot 'temp.dat' index i w lines lw 3 title sprintf('Geophone %d', i + 1)
}
unset multiplot
```

Comment: This is great, however it keeps repeating the title, the X axis label and X axis measure points. Is there a way to keep the title in the first graph and the X axis label and measure points in the last graph?