# Place key below multiplot graph in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

As the title suggests I want to place the plot legend below a multiplot graph. I add the legend for just one of the plots because the line styles are the same for all. The problem I encounter is that, if I add the key by `set key below`, the plots themselves get resized as to fit the (large) key inside the canvas. I would rather want to maintain the size of the plots. I tried adding the key as additional plot in the multiplot with `set key inside`, but then the key can overlap the plots if it is too large. I am using the epslatex terminal.

Comment: It might be helpful to create a minimal script that we can play with -- For example, where you plot a datafile, just put in a plot command plotting `sin(x)` or `cos(x)` just so that we can play with the layout to get it correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with some functions to help adjust the positions of the margins in the plot:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

### n: change this parameter to equal the number of data sets to be plotted
n = 3
# t: top margin in pixels
t = 75.0
# b: key height in pixels (bottom margin)
b = 300.0
# h: height of output in pixels
h = 150.0*n + t + b

### define functions to help set top/bottom margins
top(i,n,h,t,b) = 1.0 - (t+(h-t-b)*(i-1)/n)/h
bot(i,n,h,t,b) = 1.0 - (t+(h-t-b)*i/n)/h

### first set up some basic plot parameters
set term pngcairo enhanced size 800,h font 'FreeMono-Bold,14'
set output 'bigkey.png'

set title 'Big Key Plot'
set ylabel 'Y Axis'

set multiplot layout (n+1),1
### First plot
# change only plot command here
currentplot = 1
set tmargin at screen top(currentplot,n,h,t,b)
set bmargin at screen bot(currentplot,n,h,t,b)
unset key
unset xtics
plot sin(1*x) title 'Line 1', \
     sin(2*x) title 'Line 2', \
     sin(3*x) title 'Line 3', \
     sin(4*x) title 'Line 4', \
     sin(5*x) title 'Line 5', \
     sin(6*x) title 'Line 6', \
     sin(7*x) title 'Line 7'
### Middle plot
# copy and paste this code to make more middle plots
currentplot = currentplot + 1
set tmargin at screen top(currentplot,n,h,t,b)
set bmargin at screen bot(currentplot,n,h,t,b)
unset title
replot
### Last plot
# change only plot command here
currentplot = currentplot + 1
set tmargin at screen top(currentplot,n,h,t,b)
set bmargin at screen bot(currentplot,n,h,t,b)
set xlabel 'X Axis'
set xtics
replot
### Last (key) plot
set tmargin at screen bot(n,n,h,t,b)
set bmargin at screen 0
set key center center
set border 0
unset tics
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
set yrange [0:1]
plot 2 t 'Line 1', \
     2 t 'Line 2', \
     2 t 'Line 3', \
     2 t 'Line 4', \
     2 t 'Line 5', \
     2 t 'Line 6', \
     2 t 'Line 7'

unset multiplot
```

Here is the result:
[image]

The things you have to adjust manually are the number of plots and the size of the bottom margin, which is where the key gets drawn.  The comments generally say where you have to change things.

I put the key in a plot by itself so that it would be easy to keep the sizes of the other plots the exact same.  Plotting the number 2 when the y range is 0 to 1 keeps the lines from showing in the key plot.

This is mostly based on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848783/gnuplot-do-not-overlap-lines/13850518#13850518), which is why I have the plots all touching.  You can adjust the top() and bot() functions with an additional margin parameter if you want a gap between the plots.

Comment: Yes, this plot looks pretty much like what I have. Only I am using the automatic layout with `set multiplot layout 5,1 columnsfirst`. Is there an obvious modification for this case or is it why you are not using the automatic layout. I also have the legend as a separate plot and I experimented with changing the bottom margin for the last plot but it did not seem to have an effect ...

Comment: It would be nice to be able to just use the `multiplot layout` setup, but as far as I know it restricts the plots to all being the same size.  In your case, the key plot is bigger, so that is why it is helpful to have those functions defined to make all the plots the same size, but with the top and bottom space controlled.  One thing I should clarify: why I refer to the 'bottom margin' that is really the margin from the perspective of what is below all the plots; that is not the margin from gnuplot's perspective.  gnuplot margins are within the plot area itself.

Comment: I tried your script with the `epslatex` terminal and I suppose it will work with a few tweaks even if the key is much bigger (labels longer). The fact that `set key below` does not work now looks as a bug to me.

Comment: I wonder if the legend at the bottom be made to arrange in horizontally rather than vertically. Horizontal arrangement could help   to plot another graph as forth graph. It will be help full to know  which part of the code should be changed so that the legend display horizontal arrangement.

Answer (score 7):

Without more details, it's hard to know if this is helpful or not, but gnuplot allows you to specify the position of the key in absolute terms:

```
set key at screen 0.5,screen 0.1 #for example
```

Which might allow you to move it around to wherever you want it to be ...

Comment: Yes, thanks. I tried this bat abandoned it because it printed a key with multiple columns instead of a single one, even if I use `set key at screen 0.5,screen 0.1 left Left reverse spacing 1.5 samplen 2.5 maxcols 1 maxrows 10`

Comment: Maybe this behavior is because the legend (with long text) is actually bigger than the plot itself. But that's exactly the reason why I want to place it outside.