# Gnuplot resize with key below

Tags: size, gnuplot

When I use gnuplot I make a multiplot with 2x2 Pics. They got all the same lines with something different in there though. Thus I want them just one line title for all of them. When I scale on on below of there it resizes that special plot. Any Idea how to archieve it properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a patch recently added to the gnuplot sourceforge site ([patch 611 here](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/patches/)) which allows the addition of explicit margins around plots while keeping the plots the same size.

If you don't want to [patch and build gnuplot](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/development/index.html) yourself, you probably have to resort to setting margins manually or in a semiautomatic way, [as I have done before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712251/place-key-below-multiplot-graph-in-gnuplot/14735402#14735402).