# how to calculate or set size of gnuplot margins + labels + legend

Tags: gnuplot

We have a large spectrogram that needs to be pixel perfect (1 row = 100ms of data, 1 column = 1 frequency bin of a fft).  I use the below code to calculate the size of the plot:

```
  set terminal unknown
  sedcmd="<(sed -n '1p;" .rowstart. "," .rowend. "p' " .filename. ".csv)"
  plot sedcmd nonuniform matrix using 2:1:3 notitle with image
  xspan = GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX - GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN
  yspan = GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX - GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN
  set terminal png size (rowend-rowstart),yspan
  sedcmd="<(sed -n '1p;" .rowstart. "," .rowend. "p' " .filename. ".csv)"
  plot sedcmd nonuniform matrix using 2:1:3 notitle with image
```

rowstart and rowend are variables passed in to gnuplot which represent the frequency bins.  This works fine with one exception, it doesn't account for the space needed for the legend and labels.  How can I either calculate, or set the pixels so that:

```
[ylabels][                     PLOT             ][LEGEND]
[                      xlabels                          ]
```

PLOT will be the exact size I specify (ie: 1000x1000)

EDIT:  final calculation code for the plotsize and margins:

```
# margins and plotsize
rowstart = 2457     # rowstart/end represent the fft bins
rowend = 5734       # plot is actually rotated 90deg (rows are cols)
cols = 6970     # number of ms in plot (plotted rows)
plotwidth = (rowend - rowstart) +1
plotheight = cols
lm = 1200.00
rm = 600
tbmargin = 200.00
width = plotwidth + (lm + rm)
height = plotheight + (tbmargin * 2)
set lmargin at screen lm / width
set rmargin at screen 1 - (rm / width)
set tmargin at screen tbmargin / height
set bmargin at screen 1 - (tbmargin / height)
show margin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the exact size of the plot you want it helps a lot. If you want a 1000x1000 plot, you can start with:

```
s = 1250 # size of plot
set terminal pngcairo size 1250,1250
set output 'spectrogram.png'

# difference between l/r and t/b margins = (0.9-0.1)*1250 = 1000 px
set lmargin at screen 0.1
set rmargin at screen 0.9
set bmargin at screen 0.1
set tmargin at screen 0.9

plot ...
```

I find that doing some basic algebra and using the `*margin` commands is very helpful when fiddling with pixel-perfect plot shapes (examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148835/histogram-of-an-images-black-ink-level-by-horizontal-axis/13150000#13150000) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848783/gnuplot-do-not-overlap-lines/13850518#13850518)).

There may be a 1 px difference or so--I am not sure if the axes are drawn from 0 to 1 px or -1 to 0 as far as the plot edges are concerned.

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for, however I need to calculate the margin width.  I know I want plot to be 1000x1000 but I dont know what to make the total size so that the axes and legend will print correctly.

Comment: I do not know a way (e.g. a variable) which contains information about how wide the legend will be; you may have to guess and check to find something that works. Also, I think of the ylabels and the legend as *part* of the margin area--are you thinking of the margin as the space beyond any drawn elements?

Comment: I am thinking as the legend and labels as part of the margin area.  What I have done is added some variables so I could tweak them to the size I wanted...see code edited in the first question